# Probot version 7.2 is not starting my app

Tags: github, probot

With probot 7.2, if I create a simple `index.js` like

```
module.exports = app => {
 app.log('YYYYYYYEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHH it is working!!!!')
}
```

This export is not working, as when I run the application, I never see my log message. The `npm run dev` give those log:

```
> test@1.0.0 dev /tmp/test
> nodemon

[nodemon] 1.18.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: .env *.*
[nodemon] starting `npm start`

> test@1.0.0 start /tmp/test
> probot run ./index.js

08:46:15.243Z  INFO probot: Listening on http://localhost:3000
08:46:15.817Z  INFO probot:

  Welcome to Probot! Go to http://localhost:3000 to get started.
```

If I downgrade the version to 7.1 it is fine.

Is someone know if there is some (and which) change to do with 7.2 version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out why, so I answer myself:

On 7.1 version, there is error when your start probot without the needed env variable.

On 7.2 those errors are not showing. You need to have env variable correctly set else it will simply start but silently fail to load your setup.

The env (or `.env` file) must define:

```
APP_ID=...
WEBHOOK_PROXY_URL=...
LOG_LEVEL=...
WEBHOOK_SECRET=...
PRIVATE_KEY=...
```

The complete possible env variables are defined [in the documentation](https://probot.github.io/docs/configuration/)